# manipulation of a list of strings containing digits to output a list of of digits

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I looking for help in manipulating a list of strings where I want to extract the digits such has :

```
 x = ['aa bb qq 2 months  60%', 'aa bb qq 3 months  70%', 'aa bb qq 1 month  80%']
```

I am trying to get to :

```
[[2.0,60.0],[3.0,70.0],[1.0,80.0]]
```

in a elegant fashion.

The first number should always be an integer but the second number can be a float with a decimal value

my dirty work around is this:

```
x_split = [y.replace("%", "").split() for y in x]
x_float = [[float(s) for s in x if s.isdigit()] for x in x_split]

Out[100]: [[2.0, 60.0], [3.0, 70.0], [1.0, 80.0]]
```

Comment: Will the strings always end in `%`?

Comment: Since you're converting to `float`, any chance of non-integer numbers occurring in the string? Will there always be exactly two numbers per string?

Comment: yes, last number could be 70.5%!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to match integers and floats.

```
import re
[[float(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+\.?\d*', s)] for s in x]
```

Explanation for the regex (`r'\d+\.?\d*'`):

```
r    #  a raw string so that back slashes are not converted  
\d   #  digit 0 to 9
+    #  one or more of the previous pattern (\d)
\.   #  a decimal point
?    #  zero or one of the previous pattern (\.)
\d   #  digit 0 to 9
*    #  zero or more of the previous pattern (\d)
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at the re module. My bad, question was not clear, there is a possibility of decimal number.

Comment: can you quickly explain the r'\d+\.?\d*' I am really unfamilliar with re. thanks!

Comment: @StevenG:  Updated the answer to explain the regular expression.